# Oracle SQL Query taking longer with OR statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that takes no time at all:

```
select count(*) from mytable where processed_status = 0 and tid not in 
  (select max(tid) from mytable group by userid)
```

tid is an auto-incremented unique identifier.  I'm grabbing all the rows from mytable that are not the latest row based on userid.  These are duplicate rows and I'm discarding them.  Now I'm adding another filter to grab a specific row as well as all of the rows from the above query.  I run the following query and it runs for 10 min before I kill it.

```
select count(*) from mytable where processed_status = 0 and (tid = 5 or tid not in 
  (select max(tid) from mytable group by userid))
```

if there is a better way to grab all the duplicate rows, I would be interested in some ideas as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (
  SELECT tid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY tid DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   mytable
  WHERE  processed_status = 0
)
WHERE  tid = 5
OR     rn > 1
```

Comment: @MTO Thanks!!! Would you mind explaining what was causing the slow down in my query?  Was it the 'not in' condition?

Comment: Your query would do two table scans (or, possibly, if you have an appropriate index then it might be able to do index full scans) - one for the `SELECT MAX(tid)..` sub-query and one for the `SELECT COUNT(*)` query then it has to do an anti-join on the two queries. The query I gave only has to do a single table scan (and no joins). If you look at the execution plans for the two different queries you can see the exact operations that each are using.

Comment: @MTO I screwed my question up.  Instead of 'where tid = 5', I need it to be 'where userid = 'user1''.  This solution won't work because the 'where userid='user1'' condition is only using the inner query.  Even if user1 is included in the inner query I will not get the latest row.  I need to get just rows that are duplicates for all users and ALL rows that have userid = 'user1'.  Any ideas?